Is there a way to create a development environment with a Dockerfile on VS Code for IAR toolchain?
I am a complete beginner at writing dockerfiles and creating dev containers. I want to create a devcontainer that can be shared and used by anyone on my team that uses the IAR compiler/toolchain on vscode.
I have written this so far for my dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:24.04 as base

RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get install ca-certificates gpg wget

#Set up a directory
RUN mkdir ~/setup
WORKDIR ~/setup

#Add IAR Build Tools for Arm:
ADD [link to download] /setup/
RUN apt-get install /setup/bxarm-9.50.2.deb 

ADD [link to download] /setup/
RUN apt-get install /setup/bxarm-9.50.2.deb.sha256

ADD [link to download] /setup/
RUN apt-get install /setup/bxarm-cspy-device-support-9.50.2.deb

#Install required packages for Build Tools
RUN sha256sum --check ./bxarm-9.50.2.sha256sum
RUN apt-get install /bxarm-*.deb

#Install CMake
RUN apt-get install cmake

#Install Ninja
RUN apt-get install -y ninja-build
RUN ninja --version`

I used this repo as guidance in terms of what software I needed, but it simply is about running IAR on VS Code - nothing about a Dockerfile.
Does this dockerfile make sense? the [] parts will be filled in with files once I get the IAR licensing approved. I plan on putting this in a .devcontainer folder along with a json file, but I am not sure what else to put in this folder to make it run. As I said earlier, I am a complete beginner.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can also get inspiration from bx-docker towards a functional Docker image for IAR and then, from there, apply any further customization.
Then the image can be uploaded into your organization's private registry (i.e. docker push <private-registry>/<user>/bxarm:9.50.2) so that it can be pulled on-demand (i.e.) using a devcontainer.
For a project, it was just about creating a file .devcontainer/devcontainer.json to fulfill its requirements. Example:
{ 
  "name": "BXARM version 9.50.2",
  "image": "<private-registry>/<user>/bxarm:9.50.2",

  // For debugging
  "runArgs": ["--privileged"],

  // Suggests installation for the project's required extensions
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "extensions": [
        "ms-vscode-cpptools-extensionpack",
        "ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack",
        // For debugging
        "iarsystems.iar-debug"
      ]
    }
  },

  // etc.

  // Mount points between host and container
  "mounts": [
    "type=volume,src=LMS2,dst=/usr/local/etc/IARSystems",
    // For debugging
    "type=bind,src=/dev/bus/usb,dst=/dev/bus/usb"
  ]
}

Running the container in privileged mode (--privileged) was a necessary step for USB pass-through so that the IAR debugger probe got properly recognized.
